# Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : near ".": syntax error

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

```
q1<- dbGetQuery(conn,
                "SELECT UNIQUELETTERCODE_y , 
                        COMPLETION.MODE, 
                        COMPLETED.BY, 
                        Current.Status, 
                        Completed.by.which.group 
                    FROM Daily_Returns 
                      WHERE AgentName IS NULL AND
                            CASEID IS NULL AND
                            Completed.by.which.group = OUTBOUND AND
                            Current.Status = Completed AND
                            (COMPLETED.BY = CALL OR
                            COMPLETED.BY = CISCO OR
                            COMPLETED.BY = MOBILE) AND
                            COMPLETION.MODE =CALL 
                        GROUP BY UNIQUELETTERCODE_y
                ")
```

Using the above code keeps on prompting this Error: Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : near ".": syntax error, any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: have you tried your query on sqlite? is it a valid one?

Comment: yes, however, i believe there is an error at the WHERE conditions, so i tested by using just a SELECT * FROM Daily_Returns and it works perfectly fine, but when i added in the WHERE condtions, that is where the error comes out

Comment: That's not a valid SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo in your query. Here is a fixed query :

```
"
SELECT DISTINCT UNIQUELETTERCODE_y, 
                                 COMPLETION_MODE, 
                                 COMPLETED_BY, 
                                 Current_Status, 
                                 Completed_by_which_group 
                  FROM Daily_Returns 
                  WHERE AgentName IS NULL AND
                        CASEID IS NULL AND
                        Completed_by_which_group = 'OUTBOUND' AND
                        Current_Status = 'Completed' AND
                        (COMPLETED_BY = 'CALL' OR
                         COMPLETED_BY = 'CISCO' OR
                         COMPLETED_BY = 'MOBILE') AND
                        COMPLETION_MODE = 'CALL'
"
```

1. You have to add `'` for every where parameter like
   `'OUTBOUND'`,`'Completed'`, etc.
2. Prevent using `.` on your column name. In SQL, periods (.) are typically used to qualify table or column names, and the dot notation isn't directly supported for column names. In most cases, column names cannot contain periods.

Comment: Your second point is factually incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your query:

1. You need to quote `"` identifiers (table/column names) that have dots in them; and
2. You need to quote `'` string literals.

## Dots in column/table names

While non-standard, it is perfectly fine to have dots in column names, but to reference them you need to quote them. There are functions for that, if interested:

- `DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier` is to be used for table/column names, and it is typically a double-quote `"`, some DBMSes support brackets `[..]` as well;
- `DBI::dbQuoteString` and `DBI::dbQuoteLiteral` are used for constants, intended to mitigate risk of malevolent or accidental SQL injection; typically this is a single-quote `'`.

To fix this problem, double-quote the names with dots in them (or use the above function).

```r
sqlite <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
DBI::dbWriteTable(sqlite, "my.table", data.frame(COMPLETED.BY=1, AgentName="QUUX"))
DBI::dbGetQuery(
 sqlite, 
 'select COMPLETED.BY, AgentName from my.table')
# Error: near "table": syntax error
DBI::dbGetQuery(
 sqlite, 
 'select COMPLETED.BY, AgentName from "my.table"')
# Error: no such column: COMPLETED.BY
DBI::dbGetQuery(
 sqlite,
 'select "COMPLETED.BY", AgentName from "my.table"')
#   COMPLETED.BY AgentName
# 1            1      QUUX
```

You can *always* quote an identifier if desired, it is usually fine (there are very few exceptions with specific DBMS implementations).

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(
 sqlite,
 'select "COMPLETED.BY", "AgentName" from "my.table"')
```

## Quote string literals

As for the typo of unquoted string constants in your query, you can take a shortcut and just quote them, or you can go the safer best-practice route of using bound-parameters.

> *Side note: since we're dealing with double-quoting tables and columns and single-quoting literals, it is often useful to use R's new-ish [raw strings](https://r4ds.hadley.nz/strings.html#sec-raw-strings), using (for example)* `r"(this string has " and ' without backslashing)"`. The extra parens here are *not* included in the string, just used as unambiguous bookends.

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(
  sqlite, 
  'select "COMPLETED.BY", AgentName from "my.table"
   where AgentName = QUUX')
# Error: no such column: QUUX
DBI::dbGetQuery(
  sqlite,
  r"(select "COMPLETED.BY", AgentName from "my.table" 
    where AgentName = 'QUUX')")
#   COMPLETED.BY AgentName
# 1            1      QUUX
```

The better way to go is to use [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries).

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(
  sqlite,
  'select "COMPLETED.BY", AgentName from "my.table" 
   where AgentName = ?',
  params = list("QUUX"))
#   COMPLETED.BY AgentName
# 1            1      QUUX
```

Note that with the `params=` argument, we are now back squarely in R land, so double-quotes and single-quotes are fine. We *do not* quote the `?` anchor in the query, and add no special quotes in the data.

SQLite supports two additional ways to anchor: `$`+number, or `:`+name.

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(
  sqlite, 
  'select "COMPLETED.BY", AgentName from "my.table"
   where Agentname = $1 or AgentName = $2', 
  params = list("ignored", "QUUX"))
#   COMPLETED.BY AgentName
# 1            1      QUUX
DBI::dbGetQuery(
  sqlite, 
  'select "COMPLETED.BY", AgentName from "my.table" 
   where Agentname = :bad or AgentName = :good', 
  params = list(bad="ignored", good="QUUX"))
#   COMPLETED.BY AgentName
# 1            1      QUUX
```

One advantage to using one of these alternate methods in SQLite is that the anchor can be *reused*, whereas with the simple `?` anchor, we would need to repeat the value.

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(
  sqlite, 
  'select "COMPLETED.BY", AgentName from "my.table"
   where Agentname IN ($1, $2) or AgentName = $1', 
  params = list("ignored", "QUUX"))
DBI::dbGetQuery(
  sqlite, 
  'select "COMPLETED.BY", AgentName from "my.table" 
   where Agentname IN (:bad, :good) or AgentName = :bad', 
  params = list(bad="ignored", good="QUUX"))
DBI::dbGetQuery(
  sqlite, 
  'select "COMPLETED.BY", AgentName from "my.table" 
   where Agentname IN (?, ?) or AgentName = ?', 
  params = list("ignored", "QUUX", "ignored"))
```

While not in your question and not a problem, we can shorten the query slightly to use SQL's `IN` operator:

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(
  sqlite, 
  'select "COMPLETED.BY", AgentName from "my.table" 
   where Agentname IN ($1, $2)', 
  params = list("ignored", "QUUX"))
DBI::dbGetQuery(
  sqlite, 
  'select "COMPLETED.BY", AgentName from "my.table" 
   where Agentname IN (:bad, :good)', 
  params = list(bad="ignored", good="QUUX"))
```

The use of bound-parameters is slightly less important when your query will *always* include those string constants, though it never hurts.

---

After all of that, I suggest your expression should be one of the below (including my hint about the `IN` operator).

Bound-parameters, generally recommended and *always safer*:

```r
q1 <- dbGetQuery(
  conn,
  r"(SELECT UNIQUELETTERCODE_y , 
         "COMPLETION.MODE", 
         "COMPLETED.BY", 
         "Current.Status", 
         "Completed.by.which.group"
     FROM Daily_Returns 
       WHERE AgentName IS NULL AND
             CASEID IS NULL AND
             "Completed.by.which.group" = 'OUTBOUND' AND
             "Current.Status" = 'Completed' AND
             "COMPLETED.BY" IN ('CALL','CISCO','MOBILE') AND
             "COMPLETION.MODE" = 'CALL'
         GROUP BY UNIQUELETTERCODE_y
  )")
```

Literals:

```r
q1 <- dbGetQuery(
  conn,
  r"(SELECT UNIQUELETTERCODE_y , 
         "COMPLETION.MODE", 
         "COMPLETED.BY", 
         "Current.Status", 
         "Completed.by.which.group"
     FROM Daily_Returns 
       WHERE AgentName IS NULL AND
             CASEID IS NULL AND
             "Completed.by.which.group" = 'OUTBOUND' AND
             "Current.Status" = 'Completed' AND
             "COMPLETED.BY" IN ('CALL','CISCO','MOBILE') AND
             "COMPLETION.MODE" = 'CALL'
         GROUP BY UNIQUELETTERCODE_y
  )")
```